# rendering a partial Rails3.x + coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, coffeescript

I have the following requirement. I have a 'school' drop down and as the last options I have add new school, so if the user selects that option I want to load the new_school form as a partial via ajax.

I'm on

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
Jquery via gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Earlier with **rails < 3** and prototype I used to do it with

```
Ajax.Updater (aka Rails link_to_remote :update => 'some_div')
```

and with **rails > 3 + JQuery** I'm familiar with `*.js.erb`, and having something like

```
$("#school_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form"))%>");
```

But I'm new to `coffeescript` and I have no idea on how to do this with `coffeescript`, can someone help me :), (because I believe you shouldn't have to do a server request for this)

So far I have done following to catch the `select_tag` change event

```
$ ->
  $('#school_name_select').change ->
    unless $(this).val()
      $('school_name').html([I want to have the _new_school_form partial here])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use a hidden div.**

In general, you don't want to bother trying to mix JS and HTML. The escaping can be complicated, error-prone, and flat out dangerous due to the possibility of cross-site scripting attacks.

Simply render your form partial in a div that's not displayed by default. In ERB:

```
<div id="school_name_form" style="display: none;">
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>
```

In your CoffeeScript:

```
$ ->
  $('#school_name_select').change ->
    if $(this).val()
      $('#school_name_form').slideUp()
    else
      $('#school_name_form').slideDown()
```

I recommend using a small, tasteful transition like slide or fade. It gives your app a more polished feel.

No AJAX is required. This pattern is so common that I have an application-wide style defined as follows.

```
.not-displayed {
  display: none;
}
```

Then using HAML (if you're into that), the HTML template becomes simply:

```
#school_name_form.not-displayed
  = render 'form'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to render the form partial inside hidden div (not too correct from semantic point of view), or put the form html as `data` attribute of any relevant element, something like

```
f.select school_name, ... , data: {form: escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form"))}
```

And the Coffeescript

```
$ ->
  $('#school_name_select').change ->
    unless $(this).val()
      $('school_name').html($('#school_name_select').data('form'))
```

Comment: @dimch, thanks a lot, I will go with the option of having a hidden div, but I didnt know about :data tag thanks for that